# How to create select/update/delete statement using stored procedure safe from SQL injection

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-injection

I always prefer to use stored procedures for most **SQL commands** during development.
One example for select statement.I use this Store porcedure

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_select] (@tbl varchar(200),@col varchar(max),@cond varchar(max))
as
declare @query varchar(max)
if(@cond!=NULL)
begin
set @query='select '+@col+' from '+@tbl+' where '+@cond
end
else
begin
set @query='select '+@col+' from '+@tbl 
end
exec(@query)
GO
```

I am little conscious **SQL Injection** atacks. This way is safe from such attack or not??

Any suggestion would be appreciated...

Comment: Well, for one, you can put `QUOTENAME()` around `@col` and `@tbl` when formulating the string, assuming that all of your tables will always be in `dbo` schema and all of your users have the same default schema. However the where clause can never be truly safe if you just allow people to enter any freeform string.

Comment: You've heard of SQL injection attacks, so go find out what they are. I'm voting to close this as you need to do more learning on your own first.

Comment: @djechlin:I have heard and also have searched for it before putting this question here.I just wanted to know how can i make my work safe and whether is it possible by using store procedure as i mentioned or not...I don't think its bad to take suggestion from so experienced guys like you

Comment: @user2552779 okay, I will tell you how to make your work safe against SQL injections. First, understand what a SQL injection is. You do not understand this yet. Go research more.

Comment: @djechlin:As per my understanding..It is an string that is injected to the user input which can form vulnerable sql statement that can harm system security by many ways..Please correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: @user2552779 can you give an example of one?

Comment: Suppose if i am using a command `cmd.CommandText ="select * from login where userName=txtname.Text";`

In such type of query a user can give input in **txtname** as `Null';Delete from Employees--`. This will fire another delete statement in my database causing lose of whole Employee table.Here **--** will comment out further any command used in my application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored procedure is completely pointless and only makes it harder to write safe code.

SQL injection is not magic; it's simply input strings with quotes.
Stored procedures do not magically defend against it; they simply encourage you to pass user input as parameters (which you aren't doing).

The *correct* way to protect against SQL (and other forms of) injection is to change your application code to never concatenate arbitrary text (especially user input) into a structured langauge (such as SQL, HTML, or JSON).

Instead, use parameters, a JSON serializer, or a proper HTML escaper, as appropriate.

Comment: so, how can i make a **select statement** safe using stored procedure..As per my need i had created the above mentioned sp that is working for any type of select statement for any table..Is there any way to alter this procedure..

Comment: @user2552779: Your stored procedure is completely, utterly, pointless.  Do not use it.

Comment: Would you suggest me a way to do it safely that is not vulnerable to SQL Injection as well as also give better performance..

Comment: @user2552779: See the second half of my answer.

Comment: As per my understanding..Using command with parameter in my application code will be better..Please correct me if i am wrong..`cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [userName],[password],[userID],[userType],[lastLogin] FROM LOGIN WHERE userName=@uname AND userType='admin'";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtusername.Text);`. Take a look at this code..Is it also vulnerable.

Comment: @user2552779: Yes; that's exactly what you should be writing, except that you should not store passwords in plain text.  You should store a salted hash, using bcrypt or PBKDFv2.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks.I am using MD5 encryption for storing password.

Comment: @user2552779: MD5 is not secure, especially without salt.  You should use bcrypt or PBKDFv2.  Also, encryption is not the same as hashing.

Answer (score 0):

No.  It very vulnerable to SQL Injection.  For example, suppose someone does

```
exec dbo.sp_select '@Dummy', '(Select Null) As x; Update Employee Set Salary = 1000000 Where EmployeeName = ''me''; Declare @Dummy Table (i int); Select Null ', null
```

then the query that you build and execute is

```
select (Select Null) As x; Update Employee Set Salary = 1000000 Where EmployeeName = 'me'; Declare @Dummy Table (i int); Select Null  from @Dummy
```

and your stored procedure which is supposed to only do selects has just updated my salary to 1,000,000.